# User Accessing Other Users' Forms Using django-braces

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

A few issues here and I have searched through the docs and SO only to get more confused.

Main issue:

I have a UserProfileForm that I load into views.py:

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin, CsrfExemptMixin

class UpdateUserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, CsrfExemptMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_update')
    form_class = UserProfileForm
```

And in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UpdateUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_update'),
)
```

When I log in as `user_id 2`, I can see my own profile at `/profile/2/` but when I key in `/profile/1/`, I can edit the user profile for `user_id 1`. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? How should I limit access? Should I do it in my template instead? (I have logged in as both users before)

Sub-issues:

1. reverse_lazy does not seem to work here returning this error: `Reverse for 'profile_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` I have added a `get_absolute_url` in my model, and calling this urls.py from my main project's urls.
2. For a separate view for creating profiles, what's the best practice of preventing forms from creating duplicate keys when saving?

**Edit:**

Based on @mariodev's suggestion, I rewrote my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^create/$', CreateUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_create'),
    url(r'^view/$', UpdateUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_update'),
)
```

In views.py, I added a new class:

```
class GetProfileMixin(object):
    def get_object(self):
        profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=self.request.user)

        if profile.user != self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        return profile
```

And call the UpdateUserProfileFormView using:

```
class UpdateUserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, GetProfileMixin, UpdateView):
     model = UserProfile
     form_class = UserProfileForm
```

Left with some small issues regarding urls and duplication of foreign_key in the userprofile table when saving the object again if I revisit the createview. I believe this is a common issue and I'm missing out on the obvious answer.

**Edit 2:**

Changed the following:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    try:
        created = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = self.request.user
        profile.save()
        return super(CreateUserProfileView, self).form_valid(form)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile/')
```

Not the most elegant solution, user will retrieve an empty form even if current profile has values inside and if submitted, will just redirect to the profile page.

Comment: Do you want to limit access to another user's profile page altogether or you want to only disable editing.

Comment: Would like to limit access to another user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ad 0: Don't use ID in your profile url, just use "/profile" and fetch authenticated user data from session (request.user)

Ad 1: If you have dynamic url, you need to use "get_success_url" and then use reverse with appropriate arguments

Comment: Good idea. Changed my urls to look like the following:
`url(r'^create/$', CreateUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_create'),`

`url(r'^view/$', UpdateUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile_update'),`

Answer (score 0):

1. How to limit access:

You have to explicitly check that the id coming in the url is same as the logged in user's id. That check is missing, hence user 1 is able to see user 2's profile. Place this at the beginning of the view.

1. reverse_lazy not working:

You can directly create the url /profile/ instead of reverse matching from django urls.

1. what's the best practice of preventing forms from creating duplicate keys when saving

Before creating a new object, check if its already present and update it.

Comment: I tried adding a `try...catch` to check if a profile exists and if it does not, then save the CreateView. However, I get an error that says `null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: That means the user_id filed is not null and you are not providing it while creating the profile object. Pass user along with other parameters during UserProfile creation.